# Get IndexPath of CollectionViewCell outside of Cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, indexpath

First of all I am a newbie in swift, so be gentle. I have a problem fetching the `indexPath` of the cell outside of the cell. I want to get that index path to a function and use it to send the content to another view. The image was created programatically in the cell, it has a tap gesture recogniser sending to this function (where "`myIndex`" is defined as an `Int : var myIndex = 0`):

```
// tap image to go at the indexpath of the user
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("image tapped")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientProfile") as! PatientProfileVC
    secondViewController.userID = posts[myIndex].userID
    secondViewController.patientName = posts[myIndex].author

    print("Passed data to the other view")

    self.show(secondViewController, sender: self)


}
```

I know that I could use didSelectItem at IndexPath where I also have the declaration of the `myIndex` but I have something that will be triggered from a segue there:

```
//standard functon for item selected
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //get the index of the cell
    myIndex = indexPath.row

    print("Cell is selected")

    //perform the segue
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommentsVC", sender: self)
    print(myIndex)

}
```

and my perform for segue looks like this:` override

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

```
    print("Segue Initiated")
    feed.navigationItem.title = nil

    //if segue.destination is CommentsFullVC{
        print("Comments segue initiated")
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! CommentsFullVC
        secondViewController.questionData = posts[myIndex].postContent
        secondViewController.authorName = posts[myIndex].author
        secondViewController.date = posts[myIndex].normalDate
        secondViewController.profileImagePath = posts[myIndex].pathToImage
        secondViewController.typeOfClinic = posts[myIndex].clinic
        secondViewController.postID = posts[myIndex].postID
        secondViewController.followersForPost = posts[myIndex].followers

}
```

So my question is, how do I pass those 2 fields to the other view without using prepareForSegue? I am struggling with this for 20 hours now and still can not figure it out.

```
secondViewController.userID = posts[myIndex].userID
secondViewController.patientName = posts[myIndex].author
```

UPDATE: Got it to work thanks to Jose answer, now it looks like this... in case anybody has the same problem as I had.

```
 // tap image to go at the indexpath of the user
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("image tapped")


    let pointInCollectionView = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
    let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: pointInCollectionView)
    print(indexPath!)

    // this one works - show segue
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientProfile") as! PatientProfileVC
    secondViewController.userID = posts[(indexPath?.row)!].userID
    secondViewController.patientName = posts[(indexPath?.row)!].author

    print("Passed data to the other view")

    self.show(secondViewController, sender: self)


}
```

Comment: can you explain what is wrong with `didSelectItemAt `? It looks ok

Comment: With that part is ok, nothing wrong. I just can not implement a second segue as it dosen't exists in the storyboard. It dosen't have a segue identifier. I can not compare them in a if statement, or I don't know how if it is a possibility. Reason why I am implementing it in the: imageTapped function. It goes to the PatientProfileVC, but it taxes the default value of: myIndex witch is 0 so it shows the details that I am asking only for the first row of the collectionView. Thats why I am trying to get the indexPath somehow into the imageTapped function @JuicyFruit

Comment: It's about the second segue from the imageTapped function where I have the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the location of the `tapGestureRecognizer` in the `collectionView` and then the `indexPath` at the given location

```
let pointInCollectionView = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: pointInCollectionView)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joze, it works like a charm! You deserve a pint for this!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be easy with a Delegate of the cell but its a little bit complicated.

The easy answer should be to store the index in the "tag" property of the imageView of the tapped image then extract from the gestureRecognizer 
You can add a tag where you create the imageView and  the code where you recover the tag will look like this:

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("image tapped")
    var myIndex = 0
    if let imageView = tapGestureRecognizer.view {
        myIndex = imageView.tag
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientProfile") as! PatientProfileVC
    secondViewController.userID = posts[myIndex].userID
    secondViewController.patientName = posts[myIndex].author

    print("Passed data to the other view")

    self.show(secondViewController, sender: self)


}
```

Comment: This would have also been a good fix! Thanks anyway, I managed to solve it taking the location of the Tap gesture recogniser in the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

If your code write like below like then try this

**collection view cell for row Method**

```
cell.image = indexPath.row
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:)))
tap.accessibilityElements = [indexPath]
cell.image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Your function out side of collection view

```
func imageTapped (_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     let index = sender.accessibilityElements?.first as! IndexPath   
     print(index.row)
     myIndex = index.row
}
```